# Entity Framework navigating using navigation properties more than one level

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have Entity model classes as follows

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.webpages_Roles = new HashSet<webpages_Roles>();
    }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
public partial class webpages_Roles
{
    public webpages_Roles()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
        this.Roles_X_ApplicationModules = 
                       new HashSet<Roles_X_ApplicationModules>();
    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Roles_X_ApplicationModules> 
                                   Roles_X_ApplicationModules { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
public partial class Roles_X_ApplicationModules
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ModuleID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RoleID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> ViewPermission { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationModule ApplicationModule { get; set; }
    public virtual webpages_Roles webpages_Roles { get; set; }
}
```

.and

```
public partial class ApplicationModule
{
    public ApplicationModule()
    {
        this.Roles_X_ApplicationModules = 
                           new HashSet<Roles_X_ApplicationModules>();
    }

    public int ModuleID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Roles_X_ApplicationModules> 
                                      Roles_X_ApplicationModules { get; set; }
}
```

you can see `User` object has a navigation property to `webpages_Roles` which again has navigation property to `Roles_X_ApplicationModules` and which in turn navigates to `ApplicationModule`..

now I want to get all the ApplicationModule from User..how do I write query using navigation properties..

I tried something like this..

```
var appModules = user.webpages_Roles.SingleOrDefault()
       .Roles_X_ApplicationModules.Where(z => z.ViewPermission == true)
       .Select(x => x.ApplicationModule);
```

but problem with this is, it doesn't issue a single query to database. It splits the query to get the `webpages_Roles` at `SingleOrDefault` then another query to get the `Roles_X_ApplicationModules` based on the `RoleId` and at the end as many queries as `Roles_X_ApplicationModules` matching the condition to get the `ApplicationModule`.

How do I write the LINQ query so that a single sql query is issued to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Include()` to do this.
Example:

```
card = Cards.Include(l => l.DocumentLinks)
            .Include(l => l.Charges.Select(ch => ch.DocumentLinks)
            .SingleOrDefault(c=>c.Id==id);
```

This is for three linked Entities:

```
public class Card
{
    public Guid Id{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentLink> DocumentLinks{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Charge> Charges{get;set;}
}

public class Charge
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentLink> DocumentLinks{get;set;}
}

public class DocumentLink
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var appModules = from u in user
                 from w in u.webpages_Roles
                 from am in w.Roles_X_ApplicationModules
                 where am.ViewPermission == true
                 select am;
```

if you want eager loading then you just need to call ToList:

```
var appModules = (from u in user
                 from w in u.webpages_Roles
                 from am in w.Roles_X_ApplicationModules
                 where am.ViewPermission == true
                 select am).ToList();
```

Comment: your query is issuing more sql queries than what my approach does.. :)